# INSERT INTO SELECT with VALUES

Tags: mysql, select, insert

Is it possible to combine `INSERT INTO SELECT` with `INSERT INTO VALUES` ?

say I have :

```
table1
  Id INT
  value1 INT
  value2 INT

table2
  Id INT
  someothervalue INT
```

Now I want to insert data into table1 :

- `Id` will be the Id of table2
- `value1` is a pre-defined value and will always be `5`
- `value2` will be set to `someothervalue`

I can't just use `INSERT INTO table1(Id, value1, value2) SELECT Id, someothervalue FROM table2 VALUES(5);` So is there a way I can use both `VALUES` and `SELECT` to achieve want I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Just add the constant to the `select` statement:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (Id, value1, value2) 
SELECT Id, 5, someothervalue
FROM table2;
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the 5 dynamic and incrementing it after each `INSERT` without using auto incrementation?

Answer (score 2):

you can just use static value 5 for the `value1` like below

```
insert into table1 (Id, value1, value2)
select id, 5, somothervalue 
from table2
```